# Apache cxf interceptor how get full response body

Tags: java, soap, cxf, interceptor

I have wsdl service. All request and response saving in minio bucket. But when content too big, in minio saved only part of this content.

My Interceptor

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class LogResponseInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    private final MinioService minioService;
    private final AdministrationWebClient administrationWebClient;

    public LogResponseInterceptor(MinioService minioService, AdministrationWebClient administrationWebClient) {
        super(Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL_ENDING);
        this.minioService = minioService;
        this.administrationWebClient = administrationWebClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        try (CachedOutputStream outputStream = ((CachedOutputStream) message.getContent(OutputStream.class));
             InputStream inputStream = outputStream.getInputStream()) {

            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            minioService.uploadFile(
                    inputStream, Constantas.MinioConst.MINIO_SPV_OUT_PATH, uuid.toString(), "application/xml"
            );

            SpvRecord spvRecord = SpvRequestContext.getSpvRequest();

            spvRecord.setRequestState(RequestState.COMPLETED);
            spvRecord.setResponseXmlUrl(Constantas.MinioConst.MINIO_SPV_OUT_PATH + uuid);
            spvRecord.setFinishDate(ZonedDateTime.now());
            log.info("End spv action with {}", spvRecord);

            spvRecord.setRequestNumber(administrationWebClient.getSpvLastRequestNumber() + 1);
            administrationWebClient.createSpvRecord(spvRecord);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("### Error while get response xml");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            SpvRequestContext.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

CachedOutputStream contains only part of response body. How i can get full response body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try lowering the level of the phase.The attachment interceptor is at the receive level (version 3.3.7).

[image: Phase chain]

**To get the request** you can try this, copy the original content to be able to flush it.

```
// now get the request xml
InputStream is = message.getContent ( InputStream.class );
CachedOutputStream os = new CachedOutputStream ( );
IOUtils.copy ( is, os );
os.flush ( );
message.setContent (  InputStream.class, os.getInputStream ( ) );
is.close ( );
        
System.out.println ("The request is: " + IOUtils.toString ( os.getInputStream ( ) ));
os.close ( );
```

**To get the response**, you need made custom implementation del original

https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/main/rt/features/logging/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ext/logging/LoggingOutInterceptor.java

and modify the method onClose(CachedOutputStream cos) with this

```
        public void onClose(CachedOutputStream cos) {
        final LogEvent event = eventMapper.map(message);
        if (shouldLogContent(event)) {
            copyPayload(cos, event);
        } else {
            event.setPayload(CONTENT_SUPPRESSED);
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\nOutbound Message\n---------------------------\n");
        sb.append("ID: " + event.getExchangeId() + " \n");
        sb.append("Address: " + event.getAddress() + " \n");
        sb.append("Encoding: " + event.getEncoding() + " \n");
        sb.append("Content-Type: " + event.getContentType() + " \n");
        sb.append("Headers: " + event.getHeaders() + " \n");
        
        if(event.isTruncated()) {
            sb.append("Payload (truncated) : " + event.getPayload() + " \n");
        } else {
            sb.append("Payload: " + event.getPayload() + " \n");
        }
        
        sb.append("---------------------------");
        this.logger.trace(sb.toString());
        
        try {
            // empty out the cache
            cos.lockOutputStream();
            cos.resetOut(null, false);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // ignore
        }
        message.setContent(OutputStream.class, origStream);
    }
```

**IMPORTANT**: the limit truncate the response, set limit to max for read the entire response

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. 
This doesn't work because I need to get the body of the response, not the request.
But for request it's really work.

Comment: Okey, sorry, i add the response